# Is there a way to provide some option to SCP to show host name or IP address while prompting for pasword

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

For eg:

In my machine the pwd prompt is always displayed as "Password"

$ scp sources/update_git.sh root@xx.213.xx.xx:/sds

Password:

But I need something like below

$ scp sources/update_git.sh root@xx.213.xx.xx:/sds

root@xx.213.xx.xx's password:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure password authentication is enabled on the server. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

On the client side, set password as the preferred method

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password server2
```

It is sensible to add the keyboard-interactive method to the list in case the server has `PasswordAuthentication` disabled

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password,keyboard-interactive server2
```

I ended up adding the following to my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 120
    VerifyHostKeyDNS yes
    PreferredAuthentications publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
```